# Unable to fetch the column name in DB2

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

[image]

When I am using an expression as a column(without alias) in my query, the driver returns the column number, instead of the name

**How can I fetch the column names, instead of column numbers?**

[image]

Comment: What name do you expect to get for the column `sum(a.salary)`?

Comment: change the query to `"SELECT sum(a.SALARY) as SUM_SALARY, a.ID from Q.STAFF a group by a.ID"`  ( in other words, give a name (an alias) to the column containing the sum )

Comment: @mao, forpas - So basically I don't want the end-user to include the alias name next to the expression column explicitly, or in case if he/she forgets to include one, then also, how can I fetch the column expression itself as the alias names, just like in other DBs(Ex.- MySQL), it gets included automatically.

Comment: I believe Db2 does not offer that functionality, i.e you need to specify the alias, or the colum-name will be its ordinal position in the resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve columns by name, then give that column a name using `AS`.

Change your query to:

```
select sum(a.salary) as total_salary, a.id from q.staff a group by a.id
```

Comment: So basically I don't want the end-user to include the alias name next to the expression column explicitly, or in case if he/she forgets to include one, then also, how can I fetch the column expression itself as the alias names, just like in other DBs(Ex.- MySQL), it gets included automatically.

Comment: I'm afraid different engines behave differently. DB2 is perfectly compliant with SQL and JDBC in this respect. Maybe your code could intervene and name any unnamed column.